# CodeIgniter-style rule-based URL Routing in Expression Engine 2?

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, expressionengine

So I’m new to EE development, but I’ve got a fairly extensive experience with CI.

I’d like to set up a URL structure like this:

```
/channel-name/*
/channel-name/*/videos
/channel-name/*/shows
/channel-name/*/awards
```

The only way I can think to do it now is by using a conditional in the template. Is there a way to route the URL similar to how CodeIgniter would allow me to do it?

Again, please forgive my ignorance if I’m missing something glaringly obvious!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EE doesn't have the cool routing you might be used to in CI, Rails, etc. Instead, EE is built to handle most of the logic from a template — which is a boon to newcomers and possibly an annoyance to more experienced devs. In templates, you'll generally use conditionals based on the URL segments to accomplish your routing goals.

In your case, I would probably use embed tags pretty heavily. Embeds are a good way to get a lot of things done in EE, because they help you bypass some of the quirky parse order issues EE has with nested loops. Example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel_name" url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1"}

  {if segment_3 == "awards"}
    {embed="channel/awards" entry_id="{entry_id}"
  {if:elseif segment_3 == "shows"}
    ...
  {if:else}
    {embed="/channel/basic_entry" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
  {/if}

{exp:channel:entries}
```

Something like Switchee can make control statements like this a little better. http://www.google.ca/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=switchee

You can also use Freebie http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie (full disclosure, I made this) to tell EE not to parse some parts of the URL, which gives you a little more freedom to play around with it.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I ended up having to switch back to the template-group/template/variable method EE wanted me to use. I had started to mess around with controllers and conditionals, but I was starting to realize pretty quickly that it would turn into a nightmare. And using embeds didn't allow me to use the pagination as well as I needed to.

Comment: I'm actually about to push a beta for an EE routing extension - if you'd be interested in testing, drop me a line. dougunderscorenelson[at]gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice explanation of routes in EE. since EE is now CI2, then routing works pretty close to the same way:

http://venodesigns.net/2011/05/07/when-expressionengine-defaults-are-not-enough/

Answer (score 1):

Using categories would be the most logical taxonomy in ExpressionEngine for your needs and provide you with the desired URL structure.

By default, the ExpressionEngine URL category segments look like this:

```
/index.php/template_group/template_name/CategoryID
```

Using your example, you'd create a [Category Group](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/content_admin/category_management.html) with the following Categories:

- Videos
- Shows
- Awards

Many Developers name their template groups to match the channel name, which makes [understanding ExpressionEngine URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) logical.

Out of the box, your URL segments would look like this:

```
/index.php/channel-name/template-name/C1
```

I would recommend setting a [Category URL Indicator](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/content_admin/global_channel_preferences.html), so you can use an identifier (e.g. `category`) in your URLs for your categories instead of the unsemantic Category IDs.

The category URLS would then be something like:

```
/index.php/channel-name/category/videos
```

Taking this a step further, by [removing index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html), you could achieve:

```
/channel-name/category/videos
```

As you'll find out in ExpressionEngine, the flexibility of the URLs and templates allows for many ways of organizing and displaying your data.

For example, you could use *Tags* instead of *Categories* for grouping your data, but you'd need to use a third-party Add-On, since tagging is not included as a core feature of ExpressionEngine.

The [Solspace Tag Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tag), DevDemon's [Tagger](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tagger) and Jamie Rumbelow's [Taggable](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/taggable) are all three suitable candidates.

Comment: Would this work for a URL in which * is the entry nicename? so for instance.. /channel-name/my-channel-entry/awards. I would very much prefer not to be editing core files any more than necessary, which is what @swatkins' answer would require, but I'm still not sure that there's a way around it. I might not be totally comprehending your answer.

Comment: Where would ` /channel-name/my-channel-entry/awards ` take you? what content do you want seen with this URL structure?

Comment: The `channel-name` is the name of my template group. I'd expect that I would put a template in that group called Awards, and have it list the awards for the entry specified in the 2nd URL segment (my-channel-entry). Sorry for confusing my terms.